# Apache server response status 301

Tags: php, apache, redirect

I have some server to server communication driving a PHP program that is going awry.

I need to understand what could be causing the ***server*** triggered call to behave different from a ***browser*** triggered URL call, and how to get the server triggered call to behave identically to the browser by running the PHP program to completion.

I am working with a 3rd party remote web application that takes a lengthy amount of time to do some computation.   When I launch this web app (using a REST call) I pass it a URL of a callback PHP program that it should trigger to notify me when it is complete. My triggered callback program should retrieve the computation results (using a REST call) and then updates files on my own server.

Manually, this works fine. But as an automated call back it doesn't.

From the apache access log I can see that the remote server is calling my URL as expected, but my Apache access log is showing a server response status of 301 and my PHP program is not running:

```
54.235.170.186 - - [10/May/2015:22:20:06 -0700] "GET /apps/_recap/ReCapRetrieveOBJ-markers_v2.php?scanID=slm-mkr-6-2B-cube201505102013 HTTP/1.1" 301 610 "-" "ServerUserAgent"
```

Now if I take that same URL and query string and type it into a browser, my PHP code works perfectly, and I see these 2 records in the access log (the second line of which is a server response status of 200):

```
173.164.203.50 - - [10/May/2015:23:35:03 -0700] "GET /apps/_recap/ReCapRetrieveOBJ-markers_v2.php?scanID=slm-mkr-6-2B-cube201505102013 HTTP/1.1" 301 635 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36" 
173.164.203.50 - - [10/May/2015:23:35:03 -0700] "GET /apps/_recap/ReCapRetrieveOBJ-markers_v2.php?scanID=slm-mkr-6-2B-cube201505102013 HTTP/1.1" 200 3401 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36"
```

**Here are my questions:**

What kind of situations in my PHP code could cause the 301?

How do I get the triggered callback (with ServerUserAgent) to respond identically to the browser triggered URL?

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurred on a Dreamhost VPS server.   Our old server was running Debian, and our new server, where this problem occurred is running Ubuntu. Apparently the web server settings are different between these two OSes, so code that previously worked fine before no longer worked.

From the comments above, I was thinking there was something in my code that was causing the redirection, but now that I've found the source of the problem, I see it had nothing to do with my code at all.  Instead, it has to do with the fact that Dreamhost servers can be configured to  support calls to both  domain.com and www.domain.com,  and it does so by redirecting domain.com to the www.domain.com subdomain.

By adding the www. prefix to the URL of my callback, thereby giving the canonical URL, my problem was eliminated (no redirection occurred for either server initiated calls, nor browser initiated calls).

Answer (score 0):

Make your API call to follow redirection. For example, if using PHP and cURL.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Or, clean your web server configuration to setup no redirection.

Comment: Why is the webserver doing redirection for the server to server communication (ServerUserAgent) , but no when the URL is launched from a browser?   Where is the redirection coming from?

Comment: There is a redirection too when you connect using mozilla browser `...301 635 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh`. I refer to your question.

Comment: I'm still confused.   I don't see anything in MY code requesting redirection.  What might cause redirection to happen anyway?   I DO see that there a redirection that is happening when the Mozilla browser initiates the call, but I also see that succeeds (hence the 2nd line) while the call from ServerUserAgent terminates silently.  How can I get the ServerUserAgent call to succeed as well?

Comment: It is because of your web server configuration. Curl follow location will make the second successful call, just like using standard browser.

Comment: It may be caused by unproper usage of apache rewrite, or maybe something else.